# How can i create a Laravel API to show ads added by admin based on impression count of users?

Tags: sql, laravel, join, query-builder

I've an admin side in my laravel project where admin can add Ads along with impression and hours. For e.g if i add a add with impression = 2 and hours = 2. So, once the user have viewed this ad for 2 times then user will not be shown that Ad for the next 2 hours.

Here is the structure of admin ads table:

```
--------------------------------------
 id | image    |impressions| hours |
 1  | image.png|     2     |   6   |
--------------------------------------
```

And there's ads_impression_log where i store the log of users who have viewed an ad

```
---------------------------------------------
 id | user_id | ad_id | impression_datetime |
 1  |    1    |   1   | 2020-07-28 23:22:45 |
---------------------------------------------
```

How can i create a laravel query so, that i get specific ad impression count and if impression count is within the hours show the user next ad.

**This is my first question here. So, please ignore if there's some mistake :)**

Answer (score 0):

Ad Model

```
public function users(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(App\Add, 'ads_impression_log', 'ad_id', 'user_id')
      ->withPivot('impression_datetime');
}
```

User Model

```
public function ads(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(App\Add, 'ads_impression_log', , 'user_id', 'ad_id')
      ->withPivot('impression_datetime');
}
```

Impression count of a given user($user_id) for a given ad.($user_id)

We'll use the collection method `filter` here.

```
$user = User::with('ads')->find($user_id);

//
$ads = $user->ads->filter(function($value, $key){
    return $value->id === $ad_id;
});
```

Now you can get the count of those impressions.

```
$count = $ads->count();
```

Impressions required for that ad.

```
$ads->first()->impression;
```

You can do the comparison accordingly.

And to get the impression_date column from the pivot table you could do the following.

```
foreach($ads as $adImp){
    $adImp->pivot->impression_date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aashish for your quick reply. I'll try this code but in the mean time can you please tell me who can i handle this for a guest user. I'm creating this for mobile API where user will be seeing Ads but same applies for the guest as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how to deal with guests given this scenario, but generally, guests are handled using sessions, you can search it over the net. I'd say it again, I'm not sure about that though.

Comment: Actually i'm creating mobile API's. So, i can't use sessions but i can use device_token instead for each guest. But how can this be handled.

Comment: I don't really know, as you're managing using the logging table and that uses user_id to keep track for a user. So I'm not really sure how to go on with the guest thing. And did the above solution work for you?(for the registered user I mean)

Comment: The one where you've used filter. Should i place that code in controller?

Comment: It's your choice, if your further code in the controller needs it then do it there.

Comment: I'm getting "Undefined variable: ad_id"

Comment: Where? .If it's here `$ads = $user->ads->filter(function($value, $key){
    return $value->id === $ad_id;
});` that means you haven't set value to the $ad_id, the ad_id for which you want to get the information

Comment: Yes i haven't set that because that should come dynamic based on user's impression.
If user has already gave maximum impression on an ad then he should be shown next ad.

Comment: I wrote the query according to this statement in the post `that i get specific ad impression count`. That is why I added the ad_id there.

Comment: Let me explain you what i really need:-
`1- ad (A) Views every 2.30 hours and 2 impressions
2- ad (B) Views every 12.45 hours and 1 impression`

So, if user 1 comes into the App then we'll show him ad-1. If the user comes again after sometime then user be shown ad-1 since he didn't gave the required no. of impression. Then if he comes again then the user will be shown ad-2 then untill 2.30 hours didn't pass he'll not be shown ad again. But after 2.30 hours he'll be seeing the ad-1 again for 2 visit inside the app but we'll not show the user ad-2 because that'll repeat after 12.45 hours

Comment: I won't give you the code for this entire logic, you'll have to do it on your own, if you need any help with writing some query, relation, I'm happy to help.

Comment: I'm using:-
`$popup_ad = DB::table('popup_ads')
            ->select(DB::raw("popup_ads.id as id, popup_ads.prize_id as prize_id, popup_ads.image as image, popup_ads.image_name as image_name"))
            ->leftjoin('popupad_impression_logs', 'popup_ads.id', '=', 'popupad_impression_logs.popupad_id')
            ->where('popup_ads.status','1')
            ->where('popup_ads.impression','<=',)
            ->first();`
But i don't know how get impression for each Ad and then don't show the ads after max impression and how can i calculate for how much time the ad doesn't show.